# Assemble - {{@index}} inside loop which is inside partial

Tags: handlebars.js, assemble

I have a simple each loop in [Assemble](http://assemble.io/) as such...

```
{{#each things}}
    {{@index}}, {{title}}
{{/each}}
```

**0, hello**

**1, there**

This works fine directly inside a page, but when this code is in a partial and included in a page, the @index doesn't output anything like such...

**, hello**

**, there**

Can anyone help with why or how to do this? Any advice appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```html
{{#eachIndex things}}
    {{index}}, {{title}}
{{/eachIndex}}
```

I had the same problem, it worked for me.

Cheers,
Ales